# Find and replace content between tags

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext2

part of my HTML looks like this

```
<h4>Headline 1</h4>
<p>Content 1</p>
<h4>Headline 2</h4>
<p>Content 2</p>
<h4>Headline 3</h4>
<p>Content 3</p>
```

And I have around 50 of these "blocks". I need to wrap them around in `<div>` to restyle them and I figured I could use Find/Replace function of SublimeText2 to get all these and replace them so they look like this

```
<div>
<h4>Headline 1</h4>
<p>Content 1</p>
</div>    
<div>
<h4>Headline 2</h4>
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>
<div>    
<h4> Headline 3</h4>
<p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

I'm unable to come up with regular expression that would allow me to select and replace.

I tried `<h4>(.*)<\/p>` but it doesn't produce any results.

I also tested `/<h4>(.*)<\/p>/s` on https://regex101.com/ but it produced 1 match across the whole file.

How do I get to this?

DISCLAIMER: I'm not trying to parse god-knows-how-many things. I'm aware of the demonic nature of HTML parsing with regex.

Comment: Try [`(?s)<h4>.*?</p>`](https://regex101.com/r/mT8xW3/1) and replace with `<div>\n$0\n</div>`

Comment: is this what you need ? https://regex101.com/r/nV2gH5/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find

```
(<h4>[\S\s]*?</p>)
```

and replace

```
<div>\n\1\n</div>
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use this regex for `find`

```
(?s)(<h4>.*?</p>)
```

Comment: @JacquesMastiff glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You may need somehting like:

**find**:

```
(?sim)(<h4>.*?</p>)
```

**replace**:

```
<div>\n$1\n</div>
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nV2gH5/2)

---

PS: Make sure **dot matches line breaks** option is selected

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a capture group the following will do the job as well

```
<h4>[\w\W]+?<\/p>(?=$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JAbEt8utH9qgOecp)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC6mC2/1)